# How to get JavaScript text to show?

Tags: javascript, html

This is for a class I'm taking. Its homework out of the book for a particular chapter. The book provides some code that is purposly not working and you have to fix it. I've got it all working exept for this part where youre supposed to get some text to show up at the bottom of the screen that displays the last time the document was modified.

Ive gone over it repeatably and cant find whats wrong. Im wondering if the book has it wrong.

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function CopyRight() {
            var lastModDate = document.lastModified
            var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)

            xxx.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:8pt;'>The URL of this document is "+document.URL+"<br />Copyright Frank's Fix-t Hardware. This document was last modified "+lastModDate+".</p>"

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="xxx"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: You don't call the function. Also you shouldn't rely on ["named-properties"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). Use `document.getElementById` for selecting an element by `id`.

Comment: Sorry what I posted is just what the book has. I dont know what any of it means. This is for an HTML class, a chapter on JavaScript.

What do you mean by "you dont call the function"? And "shouldnt rely on named properties"?

So it should be "xxx.getElementsById"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working one. The code works fine but you forgot to call the CopyRight function.

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        function CopyRight() {
            var lastModDate = document.lastModified
            var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)

            xxx.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:8pt;'>The URL of this document is "+document.URL+"<br />Copyright Frank's Fix-t Hardware. This document was last modified "+lastModDate+".</p>"
        }   
        CopyRight(); // Call Copyright function
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="xxx"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

The mistakes are in your program

1. Missing closing curly `}` brace.
2. Not invoking the function `CopyRight()`
3. Inside `CopyRight()` not getting the `xxx` element to work on this.
4. Script should be invoked when the dom is ready (so placed script after `xxx` tag)

Correct version of your program is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="xxx"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CopyRight() {
            var xxx = document.getElementById('xxx'); //mistake 3 
            var lastModDate = document.lastModified
            var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)

            xxx.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:8pt;'>The URL of this document is "+document.URL+"<br />Copyright Frank's Fix-t Hardware. This document was last modified "+lastModDate+".</p>"
        } //mistake 1
        CopyRight(); //mistake 2
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```